# Vaadin appfundation authorization

Tags: vaadin, role-base-authorization

I'm using vaadin for my project.I have implemented the User authentication using vaadin appfundation plugin,I need to apply role base access(Authorization) to the my application,But I don't know how to implement this functionality in appfundation,I searched a lot on the internet but I couldn't find a good example for that ,If any one knows how to implement that function pleas let me know,As I understood I want to implement Resource ,Role interfaces in appfundation,Please help me to solve this problem.Thnxx

Answer (score 3):

You need to start by initializing a the Permissions class using a PermissionManager. So the first question is, how are you going to store your permissions? For example, if you are going to store them using JPA and AppFoundation's persistence module, then you can use the provided JPAPermissionManager. To initialize the Permissions class, call

```
Permissions.initialize(application, new JPAPermissionManager());
```

If you are not going to use JPAPermissionManager or the MemoryPermissionManager, then you need to implement the PermissionManager interface yourself and initialize Permissions using it.

The next step is to implement the Role and Resource interfaces. The Resource interface has just one method you need to implement, getIdentifier, which returns a unique string for a resource. A resource is whatever you want to protect, for example, a view. The Role interface also has a getIdentifier method which needs to be implemented, you should return a string which identifies a specific role, for example, "admin", "normal user", "power user" etc. The Role interface also has some other methods for handling role relations.

Unfortunately, the documentation is uncompleted and the best source available is probably this wiki page http://code.google.com/p/vaadin-appfoundation/wiki/Authorization

You can also try to take a look at the tests for the Authorization module, those might give you an idea how to use the module :(

Comment: but this is not clear to me ,I went through this example , thnxx for ur valuable response!!!